# Getting a ?var=value from the URL when submitting a form

Tags: php, forms, get, submit

I have a form on a page which holds in the URL `page?slot=1` and I want the form to correspond to the `slot=1` value, but it doesn't seem to transfer over to the `action="process.php"` that I have set up.

Do you have any idea on how to capture which slot is selected, and then transfer that with the form submit?

(selected_battle.php takes slot=1 and makes it $selected_battle = 1; then the insert_battle_data.php says if selected_battle=1, use the form there to such and such. but it never gets the $selected_battle=2, only 1. the selected battle php is below as well. )
FORM CODE:

```
<?php
require("selected_battle.php");
?>
<div style="float:left; margin-left:-40px; margin-top:-153px;">





        <img src="../images/upload/btn_choosefile.png" border=0 style="margin-right:0px; float:right; margin-top:20px;"/>
        </div>
    </div>


    <div style="float:left; margin-left:-468px; margin-top:40px;">

     <form action="/controlpanel/insert_upload_battle_data.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
     <?php if (isset($_GET['slot'])) { ?>
<input type="hidden" name="slot" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_GET['slot']); } ?>">
    <input type="file" name="file" id="file" style="color:#FFFFFF; background-color: transparent; border-width: 0; border-color:transparent; border-style:hidden; width:240px; height:11px; padding-left:5px; margin-left: 428px; margin-top:-174px; float:left; font:'Lucida Console', Monaco, monospace; font-size:9px; padding-bottom:5px;" />



<input type="submit" name="submit" value="" class="ready_button" border="0" style="margin-left:683px; margin-top:-175px; float:left;" />

</div>
```

SELECTED BATTLE PHP

```
<?php
$selected_battle = 1;

if (!empty($_GET['slot'])) {
    $slot = implode(',', $_GET);

} else {
    $slot = 1;
}
echo $slot;




if ($slot == 1) {
  $selected_battle=1;
}

else if ($slot == 2) {
  $selected_battle=2;
}

else if ($slot == 3) {
  $selected_battle=3;
}

else if ($slot == 4) {
  $selected_battle=4;
}

else if ($slot == 5) {
  $selected_battle=5;
}

else if ($slot == 6) {
  $selected_battle=6;
}

else if ($slot == 'q') {
  $selected_battle=7;
}

?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just include it in the form using a hidden input.

```
<form action="process.php">
<?php if (isset($_GET['slot'])) { ?>
<input type="hidden" name="slot" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_GET['slot']); ?>">
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: forgot a closing parenth and curly at the end though :)

Comment: Do I have to be using the GET method for this?

Comment: @user1765620 — You said *form on a page which holds in the URL "page?slot=1"*, getting data out of the query string of the URI is done with the `$_GET` superglobal in PHP. If you want to get the data from somewhere else then you can use a different approach.

Comment: Well yes, the FORM is also selected by the slot=1/2/3/or 4. Then that slot info needs to be sent along with the upload file form which is shown due to the specific slot number. So if slot=1 is clicked, then fileupload 1 form is initiated and needs to send that it IS in fact fileupload 1 form that is being proccessed.

Comment: that made less sense in words.

Comment: I'm an idiot. I got it, the selections had to be POST, not GET

Comment: (in the input_battle_data.php action="")
$selected_battle = $_POST['slot'];
$slot = $_POST['slot'];

Answer (score 0):

You can use either `$_GET["slot"]` or `$_REQUEST["slot"]` (`$_REQUEST` contains both `$_GET` and `$_POST` so it can be convient if you are using both)

Answer (score 0):

you may use `$_GET` or `$_REQUEST` and check in php like this,

```
  if(isset($_GET['slot']) {
    //put in the value for any input element, inside the form to be submitted.
   }
```